# If last name exists else first name | Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm a completely newbie and trying around in wordpress atm.

I have this function to get first name:

```
function get_first_name () {
    $user_data = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
    return  $user_data->first_name; 
}
```

to get the users first name (and display it somewhere afterwards). Now i want to work it like if the user has registered only with his first name it should only get the first name but if he also registered with lastname it should only (!)  get last name and ignore the first name.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Will there always be a first_name?

Comment: `return $user_data->last_name != '' ? $user_data->last_name : $user_data->first_name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple ternary statement should do it for you

```
return $user_data->last_name != '' ? $user_data->last_name : $user_data->first_name;
```

It is like the longer IF

```
if ($user_data->last_name != '') {
    return $user_data->last_name;
} else {
    return $user_data->first_name;
}
```